# If I upload a draft of my paper to arXiv, will I still be able to publish in an IEEE or ACM publication?

Tags: publications, arxiv, ieee, acm

Since IEEE/ACM will eventually own the copyright of the papers they publish, and since they charge for access to papers, if I have a paper on arXiv is that a problem for them?

Comment: You can already post your ACM paper on your page free of charge using the Author-Izer service (http://www.acm.org/publications/acm-author-izer-service), so it doesn't look like they prohibit all free-of-charge access (although of course this is under their control).

Comment: Read the relevant copyright transfer agreement. For example: http://www.acm.org/publications/ACM-PubLicenseAgreement.pdf and http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecopyrightform.pdf — in brief, yes, submitting to ArXiv is perfectly fine, just follow the details of the relevant copyright transfer agreement.

Comment: Only if you tell them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Jukka Suomela has indicated in the comments, **yes, you will**.

The relevant policy for IEEE (from http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecopyrightform.pdf) is:

> 8 . Electronic Preprints. Before submitting an article to an IEEE publication, authors frequently post their manuscripts to their own web site, their 
>   employer’s site, or to another server that invites constructive comment from colleagues. Upon submission of an article to IEEE, an author is required to 
>   transfer copyright in the article to IEEE, and the author must update any previously posted version of the article with a prominently displayed IEEE 
>   copyright notice. Upon publication of an article by the IEEE, the author must replace any previously posted electronic versions of the article with either 
>   (1) the full citation to the IEEE work with a Digital Object Identifier (DOI) or link to the article abstract in IEEE Xplore, or (2) the accepted version 
>   only (not the IEEE-published version), including the IEEE copyright notice and full citation, with a link to the final, published article in IEEE Xplore.

For ACM, from http://www.acm.org/publications/ACM-PubLicenseAgreement.pdf:

> (b) Furthermore, notwithstanding the exclusive 
>   rights the Owner has granted to ACM pursuant to Paragraph 2 (a), 
>   Owner shall have the right to do the following: [...] (v) Prior to commencement of the ACM 
>   peer review process, post the version of the Work as submitted to 
>   ACM (“Submitted Version”) to non-peer reviewed servers...

This answer is current as of August, 2014.

Comment: Just note that the IEEE copyright requirements quoted here are pretty much BS. From a moral/ethical standpoint they have no business telling you what to do with previous drafts; and legally, once you've granted non-revocable rights to, well, everyone, even if you "transfer" your copyrights to the IEEE you can just "have them back" by the terms under which it was published.  (Caveat: I am not a lawyer.)